# mod_rewrite and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have set up a few rules based on other questions but now my css breaks

I did have the URL /

```
/eshop/cart.php?products_id=bla
```

and everything work fine. but now with my mod rewrite url-

```
/product/product-title/
```

It loose the base directory. Is there an option to fix this? So i dont have to go back with the full url in all the img src tags and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

always use absolute path when link to the server resources
web-server's absolute path always starts from the `/`
So `/css/style.css` will never fail (it must be the real path of course)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I ran into this also when I started using rewritten paths. You can define the base directory in the code or just use absolute paths.